# "There is no man who has never looked upon a woman WITH/WITHOUT desire"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, negation, double-negation

In Atticus's closing speech he argues:

> “Which, gentlemen, we know is in itself a lie as black as Tom Robinson’s skin, a lie I do not have to point out to you. You know the truth, and the truth is this: some Negroes lie, some Negroes are immoral, some Negro men are not to be trusted around women—black or white. But this is a truth that applies to the human race and to no particular race of men. There is not a person in this courtroom who has never told a lie, who has never done an immoral thing, **and there is no man living who has never looked upon a woman without desire.**”

Should the last sentence end with:

> "... **and there is no man living who has never looked upon a woman without desire.**”

OR

> "... **and there is no man living who has never looked upon a woman with desire.**”

I have two copies of "To Kill a Mockingbird". One book has the first line, the other has the second line.

I would like to know which sentence would make most sense in this context. Which one is correct?

Comment: It's talking about weaknesses, so the first version (*without*) fits the theme better.

Comment: Could it be argued that a double negative turns into a positive and therefore (no man who has never =) all men "looked upon a woman with desire"?

Comment: @cdek, this is exactly his point.

Comment: The original is a hair more idiomatic, and also consistent with her style.  The second would be more confusing, though there are other ways to make it clearer (and less poetic).

Comment: @Lawrence Hmmm. The point that Atticus is making is that all men at some point have looked at a woman *with* desire. In other words there is nothing strange about the defendant regarding a woman just because he is black. So it's definitely *with* that's required here - I think.

Comment: @Araucaria That's embarrassing. I stand corrected.

Comment: @cdek Out of curiosity, do your different versions have any difference in copyright? In edition? Can you tell which one is more original?

Comment: @Lawrence I had to sit down with a pen and pencil to work it out! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we parse from the right beginning with "has never looked at a woman with/without desire" and apply it to an individual man, call him Mark, then

> Mark has never looked at a woman without desire

means that Mark desires every woman he sees.

> Mark has never looked upon a woman with desire

means that Mark is not attracted to women.

The left part of the sentence "there is no man living who" tells us that "Mark" does not exist.

So either Atticus is saying there is no man who is a total nymphomaniac, desiring every woman he ever sees (the "without" meaning); or Atticus is saying there is no man who is un-attracted to at least one woman(the "with" meaning).

Neither of these really make his point. So parsing from the left is the only way to make a meaningful expression, and this is probably the most natural way to do it anyway.

"There is no man living who has never" is identical to "every man living has, at least once".  in most cases men look upon some women with desire and others without. Every man has looked at a woman without desiring her. Every man has looked at a woman with desire.  However, only "with" makes the point Atticus was making. Every man has, at some point, looked upon a woman with desire.

The correct version is

> and there is no man living who has never looked upon a woman with desire.

but in rhetoric, as opposed to logic, both ways would be understood.

The phrasing is probably based on Matthew ch5 v28

> But I say to you that whoever looks at a woman to desire her has already committed adultery with her in his heart

Comment: Prezackerly so +1 (was going to try and answer this question but was tying myself in knots ...)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I would have sworn that it had to be 'without', but after a lot of pondering, it seems that 'with' makes most sense.

Comment: *So either Atticus is saying there is no man who is a total nymphomaniac* is an unusual use of *nymphomaniac*.

Comment: A tour de force +1

Comment: Even parsing from the left, Atticus is of course wrong: there are plenty of men who have never looked at a woman with desire. Apart from the many gay and asexual men who have looked upon women, but never with desire (and who, admittedly, were much less likely to be at the forefront of readers’ and jurors’ minds in 1960 than they would be now), there are also many blind men who have never looked upon a woman full stop!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Very true Janus. Atticus statement is incorrect, but it is what he was trying to say.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "parsing from the right" and "parsing from the left". I also don't understand what you mean by "in rhetoric, as opposed to logic, both ways would be understood". Both possible sentences are correct; however, only the latter appears to make a point for the speaker, since "having looked upon a woman with desire" can be seen as a weakness or as potentially leading to an immoral act, but "having looked upon a woman without desire" is a bit harder to see as a weakness or as something immoral.

Comment: @Stef  Atticus was, I think, defending a client. His client had desired a woman, but Atticus points out, so has everybody else. Someone has lied, but so has everyone else at some point. He was trying to say that his client's weaknesses and faults are actually simply those common to all humanity. His client is therefore no more guilty than anyone else.

Comment: @Stef Re parsing from the left or right, it means a way of making sense of a sentence. "I saw a lion in the car" can be parsed from the left as (I saw the lion) in the car. I saw the lion, and the place I was when I saw it was in the car. But parsed from the right it  is I saw (the lion in the car). There was a lion in the car, and I saw it. Where I saw it from is not stated.  I saw the moon in the bathroom. I saw the cup he won for bowling on the mantlepiece.

Comment: @Stef By rhetoric and logic I mean that sometimes we understand the meaning of a sentence in a certain way, even if logically it could mean something else. I saw the moon in the bathroom can only mean one thing really. In logic there are two possibilities but rhetorically we know what the speaker meant. "We have a slight problem" logically means a small issue, but in the UK it really, that is rhetorically, means a serious problem.  It is a British understatement. In joint British and American military operations it can cause misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t want to pick on anyone in particular, but for clarity’s sake, I have to point out that Lawrence has it backwards. With the “without” version, what Atticus says can be expressed as

~ ∃ x (M x · ~ ∃ t ∃ y [W y · ~ L x y t])

where

M x means x is a living man;

W y means y is a woman;

L a b t means that a looks on b with desire at time t.

If we minimize the scope of the negations, that expression becomes:

∀ x (~ M x ∨ ∃ t ∃ y [W y · ~ L x y t])

or

For any entity, either that entity is not a living man, or there’s some time when there’s some woman whom that entity (man) does not look on with desire

which is true, but, judging from the context in the novel, is not what Atticus meant. I suggest that the “without” was to begin with a typo.

Comment: Have you read all the comments? Lawrence said 'I stand corrected' six years ago (four hours after the comment you are responding to).